# DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer not publishing the "original payload" on the .DLT topic

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using `spring-kafka-2.2.9.RELEASE` and `kafka_2.12-2.3.0`.
I have been trying to get the `original payload` in the .DLT topic, but all i get is "null". I am sure this can be done using the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2`, `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`, but i am not sure what i am missing.

**Producer & Consumer**

```
Producer:
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put("acks","all");

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object>(props, new JsonSerializer<Object>(objectMapper), new JsonSerializer<>());
        //return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object>(props, new JsonSerializer<Object>(objectMapper), new JsonSerializer<Object>(objectMapper));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>(producerFactory());
    }

Consumer:
@Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

        JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(objectMapper);
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        ErrorHandlingDeserializer2<Object> errorHandlingDeserializerKey = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer2<>(jsonDeserializer);
        ErrorHandlingDeserializer2<Object> errorHandlingDeserializerValue = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer2<>(jsonDeserializer);     

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, errorHandlingDeserializerKey, errorHandlingDeserializerValue);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), 3));

        return factory;
    }
```

I see "null" in the topic.DLT:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic.DLT --from-beginning
null
null
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently consume DLT records (published because of a serialization exception) with a `@KafkaListener` in 2.2.x because the `DeserializationException` header is detected by the container so the DLT record itself is sent to the error handler.

I have just [fixed this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1271) and it will be available in 2.2.11.

However, if you use a regular `KafkaConsumer` you can use this code to get the original value...

```java
Header exHeader = record.headers().lastHeader(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
DeserializationException ex = (DeserializationException) new ObjectInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(exHeader.value())).readObject();
System.out.println("DLT: " + new String(ex.getData()));
```

Note: if you use a function as suggested by Artem, the record will go to your main listener, not the error handler, so you have to deal with it there. So you will need some kind of dummy value containing the original payload.

It is certainly easier if you can upgrade to 2.3.1.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I went for the easier option you recommended, i.e upgrade to 2.3.1, it worked like a charm! You guys rock! The only hiccup was that my offset was not moved to the next and stayed on the message that was having the issue. After troubleshooting, i found that if i set consumer config `enable.auto.commit` to `true`, then the offset would move past the current to the next message. Do let me know if i am wrong here i.e there is something else i need to do. Thanks again!

Comment: I prefer not to use `auto.commit.offset` - the commits are done in the background indeterminately; it's much better to have the container do the commits reliably either after each poll (default) or even record (`AckMode.RECORD`). The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` does have a property `commitRecovered` but that is intended for when you are doing manual acks (`AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`). The container has a property `ackOnError` but that's no good because it will commit on the first failure and there is a race condition between that commit and when we do the seeks. I need to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` there is a logic like:

```
private T recoverFromSupplier(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data, Exception exception) {
    if (this.failedDeserializationFunction != null) {
        FailedDeserializationInfo failedDeserializationInfo =
                new FailedDeserializationInfo(topic, headers, data, this.isForKey, exception);
        return this.failedDeserializationFunction.apply(failedDeserializationInfo);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, if a `failedDeserializationFunction` is not provided deserialization data is returned as `null`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

> If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` returns a null value and a `DeserializationException` in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes.

Comment: Or you can upgrade to 2.3.1 where the value is now populated from the failure. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/988

Comment: Also see my answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem for chipping in, Gary's recommendation was what i needed, but it's always good to know the logic you mentioned.